# Data plotting iOS - CSV file

Tags: ios, csv

I have a csv file that is updated every second on a client. This file is synced with a server which holds the file. An iOS application reads this file using 'contentofURL'. Instead of reading is it possible to store the file data - like receive only the updated values instead reading the whole file? These values are later plotted using core plot API

Answer (score 0):

You need your server to be able to provide the updates of your data.
If your CSV file only grows by appending new values, you can make a service that would accept an index as a parameter and return all elements starting from that index.
Then in your client you request that service with the index equal to the number of elements already retrieved by the client, and then append the returned elements to the stored ones.

If your CSV file changes in more complicated ways then you will need some kind of version numbers and a service that accepts a version number and returns a diff between that version and the latest one, together with the latest version number.